# The type `System.Xml.XmlElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly System.Xml

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

I tried to import an external library to my project, but I'm receiving an error:

> Error CS0012: The type `System.Xml.XmlElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly`System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

System.XML (2.0.5.0) is added to the project. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that you are using an 'external library'

Is this a library that has been built for Xamarin.iOS? Or is it a more conventional .Net assembly.

Because Xamarin.iOS is based originally on Moonlight (which used the Silverlight assemblies), then you cannot just pull in external assemblies - you should recompile these assemblies specifically for Xamarin.iOS

Comment: Yes, I'm using an assembly that was not specifically built for Xamarin.iOS - Jabber-Net 2.1.0 for Mono
https://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/downloads/list

I'll try to recompile the source code of the library.

Comment: what is the process of recompiling an external library for Xamarin.iOS?